# Feeding JQuery autocomplete from mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to create an autocomplete field using JQuery, which receives its autocompletions from a mysql database.

**Index.php:**

```
        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $("#college").autocomplete({
                source: "search.php",
                minLength: 2
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"  method="post">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>jQuery UI Autocomplete Example - PHP Backend</legend>

            <label for="state">State (abbreviation in separate field): </label>

            <input type="text" id="college"  name="college" />

            <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Submit" />

            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo "<p>";
    while (list($key,$value) = each($_POST)){
    echo "<strong>" . $key . "</strong> = ".$value."<br />";
    }
echo "</p>";
}
?>




        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->


        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
            (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**search.php:**

```
/* Connection vars here for example only. Consider a more secure method. */
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'college';

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$return_arr = array();

if ($conn)
{
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM college_list where name like :term";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
    $result->execute();

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }


}
/* Free connection resources. */
//$conn = null; 
/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

It's currently retrieving correctly from the database, because it's getting the correct number of autocompletions. However, they're all blank. It appears to not actually be feeding "name" back into the field and I can't seem to figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: _It's currently retrieving correctly from the database, because it's getting the correct number of autocompletions_ - Check the request/response in the network tab to see if the data is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the autocomplete code you are using, I would say that you need a 1-dimensional array instead of a 2-dimensional one as you are generating now.

You could try changing:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
```

To:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($return_arr, $row['name']);
}
```

**edit:** check the [api documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), you need to build your array differently, something like:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($return_arr, array('label' => $row['name'], 'value' => $row['name']));
}
```

Comment: The autocomplete code I'm using is just from the JQuery UI library.

This fix makes sense to me, but when I implement it the form now returns no autocompletions.

Comment: read the autocomplete docs... you need `label` and/or `value` keys in data os just pass strings with no associative array in php